# How to draw a rectangle over an image and save it in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, image, highlight

I have used the following code to draw a rectangle on the image buI i an not able to save the image with the highlighted rectangle. Only the original image is saved not the image with the rectangle. Please help me with this.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
  If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
    IsMouseDown = True
    SelectedObjPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
  If IsMouseDown = True Then
    If e.X < SelectionBoxObj.X Then
      SelectionBoxObj.X = e.X
      SelectionBoxObj.Width = SelectedObjPoint.X - e.X
    Else
      SelectionBoxObj.X = SelectedObjPoint.X
      SelectionBoxObj.Width = e.X - SelectedObjPoint.X
    End If

    If e.Y < SelectedObjPoint.Y Then
      SelectionBoxObj.Y = e.Y
      SelectionBoxObj.Height = SelectedObjPoint.Y - e.Y
    Else
      SelectionBoxObj.Y = SelectedObjPoint.Y
      SelectionBoxObj.Height = e.Y - SelectedObjPoint.Y
    End If
    Me.Refresh()
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
  IsMouseDown = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
  If SelectionBoxObj.Width > 0 And SelectionBoxObj.Height > 0 Then
    Dim oGradientBrush As Brush = New Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF, SelectionBoxObj.FillColor, SelectionBoxObj.FillColor, Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Vertical)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(oGradientBrush, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF)

    Dim TempPen = New Pen(SelectionBoxObj.BorderLineColor, SelectionBoxObj.BorderLineWidth)
    TempPen.DashStyle = SelectionBoxObj.BorderLineType
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(TempPen, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF.X, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF.Y, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF.Width, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF.Height)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Highlight_Ok_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Highlight_Ok.Click
  Dim datestring As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddmmss")
  Dim path As String = "D:\capture screenshot temp"
  Dim currentsavepath As String = String.Format("{0}\capture_{1}.png", path, datestring)
  PictureBox1.Image.Save(currentsavepath, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't drawing on the image but on top of the image. Instead of using e.Graphics, you'll have to create a graphic object from the image by using [FromImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ...and dispose of your brushes and pens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectangle you are drawing in the PictureBox is a temporary drawing.  It's showing the current image with the rectangle drawn on top of it.  But when you are saving the image, the rectangle isn't a part of the image.

You can remedy your situation by moving your drawing routine into a procedure that will draw the result in a graphic object you pass to it:

```
Private Sub DrawHighlight(g As Graphics)
  If SelectionBoxObj.Width > 0 And SelectionBoxObj.Height > 0 Then
    Using br As New SolidBrush(SelectionBoxObj.FillColor)
      g.FillRectangle(br, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF)
    End Using
    Using p As New Pen(SelectionBoxObj.BorderLineColor, SelectionBoxObj.BorderLineWidth)
      g.DrawRectangle(p, SelectionBoxObj.RectangleF)
    End Using
  End If
End Sub
```

Now you can update the screen easily:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
  DrawHighlight(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

and you can save the final results:

```
Using bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
  Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    DrawHighlight(g)
  End Using
  bmp.Save(currentsavepath, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Using
```